# Android : making phone numbers callable

Tags: javascript, android, browser

On Android, I want to make phone numbers on webpages callable by clicking on them - similar to Gmail app.

To do this for any arbitrary phone number on any arbitrary page, do I use JavaScript to parse the phone numbers and replace them with the `tel:` URL? More important, What happens when such a number is clicked (I am familiar with placing calls from app. Can I just do that?)? How would I run the JavaScript? Extension for Android stock browser?

I apologize if this is too general a question. Any information is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I swear I just 5 minutes ago saw this on my phone and I was going to ask too :-)  On my phone, what happens is that the phone brings up the dialer with the phone number pre-populated.  I suspect it's just a special URL scheme but I don't know what it looks like.

Answer (score 3):

What works for me on Android is something like this:

```
<a href='tel:2125551212'>Call Me Now!</a>
```

When I click such a link from my Android phone, the phone brings up the dialer pre-populated with that phone number.

Comment: Thanks, yes - that would work. 
1. But how to add capability to browser? how to do on-the-fly JS parsing? extensions?
2. i can catch the intent that brings up the dialer...

Comment: ? Capability to browser? What I mean is that the browser on (at least) my Android phone *already* does that.  I don't know about Android programming directly; this is just a purely web (browser) solution.  There's nothing at all you have to do in code other than place the `<a>` tag with the "tel:" URL on the page.